# How send anchor to URL with render() Yii

Tags: html, yii, anchor

Hi i wont render view with anchor location - http://example.com/index.php#top

may be like this:

```
$this->render('index', ['data' => $data], 'anchor'=>'top');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When asking, you shall take care to ask properly. Your question is very short, full of errors, not possible to understand, what you are asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `render` the url is already set because you are in the `controller` (or the `view`). So you can't add an anchor to the url at this time.

You must set the anchor before the controller is called.To do it you can set an anchor when you create the url:

```
$this->createUrl('controller/action', array('#' => 'the-anchor'));
```

You could also use `redirect` to redirect the visitor to the page with the anchor

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action', array('#' => 'the-anchor')));
```

but I think that set the anchor when you create the url is the best way to achieve what you want.